# Control HTML5 Video Fullscreen attribute

Tags: html, video

Is it possible to define fullscreen HTML5 video attribute? Let's say, I only want to make the fullscreen shows 30% of the video.

What I want to achieve is to open 3 browser tab, the first tab shows 33% of the video, second tab 33% and the third tab shows 33% of the video. BUT, this three tab must be full screen.

Any alternative or method is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all three video element inside a div and then fullscreen the div.